# obtaining epoch date from files in directory to define age for deletion

Tags: bash, macos, date, terminal

I am trying to write a bash script to go through the files within a directory, obtain each and every file's epoch date and compare it against today's epoch date. If the file is older than X amount of days, delete it.

I keep getting an error on the date command with "+%s" option (Using MacOS)
The command > +%s> actually works while running directly on terminal, but as integrating it into a for loop it returns an error

The error is: ./listfiles.sh: line 8: date -r DeleteThese/ACME.txt +%s : syntax error in expression (error token is "DeleteThese/ACME.txt +%s ")

```
#!/bin/bash
tdyepoch=`date +%s`
thepath="DeleteThese/"
thefiles=$(ls -1 $thepath)
for i in $thefiles
do

        file_epoch=$(( date -r $thepath$i +%s ))
        ttl=$(( tdyepoch - file_epoch ))
        mins=$(( ttl / 60 ))
        hrs=$(( min / 60 ))
        dys=$(( hrs - 24 ))
        echo "$i, $file_epoch, $ttl, $mins, $hrs, $dys"
done
```

What is what I am doing wrong here...? I am not new to bash, but this one has me stomped for some odd reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `$((...))` there?

Comment: Also you should read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and [why not parse ls and what to do instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 1):

`$((...))` does arithmetic expansion. You need `$()` around your `date` call for command substitution instead. Plus you [shouldn't try to use the results of ls in a loop](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), instead using normal filename expansion. You have a few other problems too like misspelled variable names that running [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on your script should alert you too as well.

Cleaned up:

```
#!/bin/bash
tdyepoch=$(date +%s)
thepath="DeleteThese"
for file in ${thepath}/*
do
        file_epoch=$(date -r "$file" +%s)
        ttl=$(( tdyepoch - file_epoch ))
        mins=$(( ttl / 60 ))
        hrs=$(( mins / 60 ))
        dys=$(( hrs - 24 ))
        echo "$(basename "$file"), $file_epoch, $ttl, $mins, $hrs, $dys"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much... !!! This seems to be what I needed... Not exactly sure why is it that I was stuck... Not my first script but it certainly looks like it is!!! ... I am very grateful for the assistance.